# communication complexity lower bound for computing median

Tags: reference-request, communication-complexity

In the textbook by [Kushilevitz/Nisan](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=264772), they give an $O(\log n)$-bit protocol for computing the median in the standard 2-party model of communication complexity, where Alice is given a set $X \subseteq [n]$ and Bob is given $Y \subseteq [n]$ and they need to output the median of the **multiset** $X \cup Y$.

However, it is not mentioned whether there is any non-trivial lower bound. Thus, my question is:

> Are there any non-trivial lower bounds known for finding the median in the 2-party model?

Comment: Isn't there a trivial $\Omega(\log n)$ lower bound because there are $n$ possible outputs?

Comment: Oh I see. There are $\Omega(n)$ distinct outputs and hence the protocol tree must have at least $\Omega(n)$ distinct leafs, which means that we need $\Omega(n)$ distinct transcripts and hence $\Omega(\log n)$ bits, right?

Comment: That is correct.